# How to eagerly return in RxJava when combining multiple Observables?

Tags: android, rx-java

Say I have 3 conditions to check. In imperative programming, I would write

```
boolean foo(A a, B b, C c){
  if(a.meetsCriteria()){ return true; }
  if(b.meetsCriteria()){ return true; }
  if(c.meetsCriteria()){ return true; }
  return false;
}
```

Here's my foolish attempt to convert the above to reactive

```
Observable<Boolean> foo(A a, B b, C c){
  Observable.zip(
    a.meetsCriteria(),
    b.meetsCriteria(),
    c.meetsCriteria(),
    (bool1, bool2, bool3)->{return bool1 | bool2 | bool3;}
}
```

The problem here is that all 3 `meetsCriteria()` methods are called, hence this implementation does not return eagerly. I would like B and C's `meetsCriteria()` to not execute when `A.meetsCriteria()` returns true. What would the correct reactive conversion be?

Comment: Nice puzzle actually, thanks :)

Comment: to not execute one based on another, you need to call them serially. So the point of trying to combine them in an observable rather than simply using a short-cutting `||` is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You just need another operator. Rather than `Observable.zip`, you could use a sequence of flatMaps:

```
a.meetsCriteria().flatMap(
    resa -> resa ? Observable.just(true) : b.meetsCriteria().flatMap(
         resb -> resb ? Observable.just(true) : c.meetsCriteria()
    )
)
```

However, this would essentially make code serial in the worst case (all three criteria are false).

So to benefit from reactive programming, you have to run all of them at once. I've come up with the following idea:

1. `merge` the observables (they will run in parallel)
2. `filter` out `true` values emitted by any of them
3. use the `defaultIfEmpty(false)` operator, which is the fallback for the case when all of the observables emitted `false`
4. finally, just use `first()` so we you a single boolean value as a result.

You can try that yourself:

```
Observable<Boolean> a = Observable.just(false).delay(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Observable<Boolean> b = Observable.just(true).delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Observable<Boolean> c = Observable.just(false).delay(50, TimeUnit.DAYS);

final Observable<Boolean> res = Observable.merge(a, b, c)
            .filter(item -> item == true)
            .defaultIfEmpty(false)
            .first();

System.err.println(res.toBlocking().first());
```

On my machine that runs in about `5` seconds, which is exactly the time that observable `b` needs to emit `true`. If you however do:

```
Observable<Boolean> b = Observable.just(false).delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

, you are doomed to wait 50 days for the observable `c` to finish :) Well, it's obviously no way to know if `c` will emit anything at all for the merge operator, so this is kinda inevitable.

Of course, you still benefit from parallelism, if you try:

```
Observable<Boolean> a = Observable.just(false).delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Observable<Boolean> b = Observable.just(false).delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Observable<Boolean> c = Observable.just(false).delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

, the total running time would be about 10 seconds, rather than 30 seconds in serial version.

P.S. also came up to an alternative solution, I feel like it's more natural. Hope the code is self-explanatory:

```
final Observable<Boolean> res = Observable.combineLatest(
    a.startWith((Boolean)null),
    b.startWith((Boolean)null),
    c.startWith((Boolean)null),
    (Boolean b1, Boolean b2, Boolean b3) -> {
        // note that b1/b2/b3 might be null
        // we interpret that as 'unfinished' computation
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(b1) || Boolean.TRUE.equals(b2) || Boolean.TRUE.equals(b3)) {
            // if any of source observables has finished and was true, the result is obviously true
            return true;            }
        if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(b1) && Boolean.FALSE.equals(b2) && Boolean.FALSE.equals(b3)) {
            // if all of source observables have finished and are false, the result is false
            return false;
        }
        return null; // otherwise we're in some kind of intermediate state
    }
)
    .filter(item -> item != null)
    .first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... how about this:

```
return Observable.concatMap(
          a.meetsCriteria(),
          b.meetsCriteria(),
          c.meetsCriteria())
      .filter(value -> value)
      .takeFirst();
```